# Applying Multiple Filters in Parallel Flink DataStream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to run a Flink Streaming application that works on the read-once-write-many analogy. Basically, I would like to read from a firehose, apply different filters in parallel for reach record read from source, and send them to different sinks based on configuration.

How is this possible to do in Flink? I think in KafkaStreams there is a concept where you can do this. Below is an illustration of how I want my Flink DAG to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way to accomplish this would be through the use of the [`filter()`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/FilterFunction.html) transformation as demonstrated below:

```
DataStream<X> stream = ...;

// Filter 1
stream
    .filter { x -> x.property == 1 }
    .sinkTo(sink1)

// Filter 2
stream
    .filter { x -> x.property == 2 }
    .sinkTo(sink2)

// Repeat ad nauseum
```

Alternatively, you could use consider using [Side Outputs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/) such that you'd only require a single "filter" function which could handle separating each of your filtered streams into separate outputs that you could then act upon.

If you absolutely require *n* different streams, you might have to look at the type of sink that you intend to write to and consider handling the filtering at that level

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of streams, then you definitely want to use a ProcessFunction with side outputs, as Rion noted above. Otherwise you're replicating the data stream N times, which is very inefficient.

One example of splitting a stream this way is found in the flink-training repo in GitHub - see the [RideSplitSideOutputSolution](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/blob/3c95dd421c3e956e395b9730d04e7e3183223f9f/ride-cleansing/src/solution/java/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/ridecleansing/RideSplitSideOutputSolution.java) class.

Comment: Yeah I am expecting to have a lot of streams - any example that I can refer to?

Comment: Added more text to my solution, with a link to an example.